# Процедура для выборки данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо написать процедуру для выборки данных, в которой некоторые критерии отбора не принимались бы во внимание, если пользователь не ввёл значения. Провожу фильтрацию данных так:

```
WHERE @ts = [ts] or @username = [username] 
or @ip = [ip] or @my_category = [my_category]
or @my_name = [my_name] or @nm1_name = [nm1_name]
or @param = [param] or @short_descr = [short_descr]
```

При вызове хранимой процедуры, когда передаю один из параметров, фильтрация работает, а когда несколько, то работает 1 фильтрация (т.к в логике у меня `or`). Заменил на `and`, но не устраивает, т.к придется передавать все параметры, а мне нужно передавать лишь те, по каким хочу отфильтровать.

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать логику правильно.

Comment: попробуйте как-нибудь так:

    ...
    and ([field] = @value or @value is null) 
    ...

Comment: Замечу еще - для большого количества данных и большого количества таких условий иногда полезно использовать хинт WITH RECOMPILE

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в условия запроса подставить проверку вводимых значений на null через or, а общие условия через and:

```
 WHERE 
 @ts = [ts] or @ts is null) and
(@username = [username] or @username is null) and
(@ip = [ip] or @ip is null) and
(@my_category = [my_category] or @my_category is null) and
(@my_name = [my_name] or @my_name is null) and
(@nm1_name = [nm1_name] or @nm1_name is null) and
(@param = [param] or @param is null) and
(@short_descr = [short_descr] or @short_descr is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ([ts] = coalesce(@ts,[ts]) or ...
```

и так далее

Answer (score 0):

```
where
...
(@my_category is null or (@my_category is not null and [my_category]=@my_category)
...
```

если принять
`@my_category` - это введённое пользователем значение
`[my_category]` - поле в БД

Остальные условия аналогично.

Comment: Запишем это в булевом виде: x + (-x & y). Дизъюнкция относительно конъюнкции дистрибутивна:  (x+(-x)) & (x+y). Нам известен закон исключенного третьего не так ли?: x+(-x) = истина - получаем 1&(x+y). И мы знаем, что 1&A = A. Получается что отрицание икса лишнее: @my_category is null or [my_category]=@my_category